# itunesconnection ATS year end self classification report

Tags: ios, app-store-connect, app-transport-security

I have a very, very basic app that makes a web service call from a `http` url in order to retrieve facts about a number that a user inputs into a textfield. In order to bypass ATS, I went into the `info.plist` and created an exception domain for the web service only.

Before I submit my app, I get the question:

- If you are making use of ATS or making a call to HTTPS please note
  that you are required to submit a year-end self classification report
  to the US government

Am I required to do this? What does this mean exactly?
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If, as you state, you are using HTTP, which is not encrypted, there is no need for you to submit the request.

> If you are **making use of ATS** or **making a call to HTTPS** please note
>   that you are required to submit a year-end self classification report
>   to the US government

You are disabling ATS so that you can make an HTTP call, so you do not meet the criteria for apps that would require a self classifaction report.